# Ignore parent layer transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transform, layer, catransform3d

I have a CALayer with 9 sublayers, which occasionally flip vertically and I use `CATransform3D` to do so. Now, my problem is that, sometimes, I need to apply a transformation to the super layer of those 9 layers. When I do that, the position and transformation of the sublayers gets all screwed up. Is there a way to ignore the transform of the parent layer, so that it doesn't affect the sublayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the layer tree is to inherit attributes like transforms. If you don't want certain layers to inherit from their parent, insert them as another layer's children.

You could also apply the inverse transform to the child layers, but that would be hackish, compute-intensive, and open the door to rounding errors.

Comment: Also, if the parent layer's anchor point and child layer's anchor point do not coincide, it is difficult to compute the correct inverse transform.